# My MySQL SELECT Query is Returning Multiples of the Same Rows

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, rows

For some reason I'm getting just one duplicate row that I can see, but can't really pinpoint where in the query I've gone wrong.

```
$stmt = $mysqli->query("
    SELECT DISTINCT vendors_tbl.email AS email,
    (vendor_avails_tbl.standard_pricing - vendor_loc_tbl.offpeak_time_pricing) AS best_margins,
    vendor_loc_tbl.location_id AS locationID,
    vendor_loc_tbl.loc_img_path AS locImg, 
    vendor_loc_tbl.offpeak_time_pricing AS offpeak,
    vendor_loc_tbl.address1 AS address1,
    vendor_loc_tbl.address2 AS address2,
    vendor_loc_tbl.zip_code AS zip,
    vendor_loc_tbl.geocodes AS geo,
    vendor_loc_tbl.has_valet AS valet,
    vendor_loc_tbl.has_transport AS transport,
    vendor_loc_tbl.has_wheelchair AS wheelchair,
    vendor_loc_tbl.has_desk AS desk,
    vendor_loc_tbl.has_24hours AS open24hrs,
    vendor_loc_tbl.has_covered AS covered,
    vendor_loc_tbl.has_security AS security, 
    (vendor_avails_tbl.available_economy + vendor_avails_tbl.available_standard + vendor_avails_tbl.available_midsize + vendor_avails_tbl.available_truck_suv) AS avail_total, 
    vendor_avails_tbl.standard_pricing AS standard_pricing, 69 *
    DEGREES(ACOS(COS(RADIANS($e_lat))
         * COS(RADIANS(SUBSTR(vendor_loc_tbl.geocodes, 1, 10)))
         * COS(RADIANS($e_lon) - RADIANS(SUBSTR(vendor_loc_tbl.geocodes, 13)))
         + SIN(RADIANS($e_lat))
         * SIN(RADIANS(SUBSTR(vendor_loc_tbl.geocodes, 1, 10))))) AS distance_in_m
    FROM vendors_tbl
    INNER JOIN vendor_loc_tbl ON vendor_loc_tbl.vendor_id = vendors_tbl.vendor_id
    INNER JOIN vendor_avails_tbl ON vendor_avails_tbl.location_id = vendor_loc_tbl.location_id
    WHERE vendor_avails_tbl.available_standard > 0
    ORDER BY vendor_loc_tbl.override_level DESC, best_margins DESC, distance_in_m ASC
    LIMIT 5
");
```

Comment: Ow, my eyes, I can't see anymore... ! Please format your question so we can read it !

Comment: please format your code. according to what I see, your join condition might give multiple vendor_loc_tbl or vendor_avails_tbl for a given vendors_tbl

Comment: could you please add table schemas and FK definitions so we can fix your join?

Comment: If I had to guess, you have multiple records in vendor_Avails_tbl for a given location having a .available_Standard > 0 when you're only expecting one.  If this returns one row then the location listed has 2 avaialble_standard records > 0 when you're only expecting 1. `Select count(1), Location_ID From vendor_avails_tbl  where available_Standard > 0 group by Location_ID having count(1) > 1`  To correct, you may just need to subquery to return distinct values relevant to that location, or you have a data problem.

Comment: You're not getting any duplicate rows.

Comment: Strawberry is correct. I had double entries in my database. So sorry to have wasted you guys' time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your distinct create the group of all the fields you have specified as you did not specify the group by condition.
So there is no chance to get duplicate value.

Comment: You're correct. I'm upvoting this as the correct answer, since you had the best explanation and answered this separately.

Answer (score 1):

Well In some cases it's bettor to use `GROUP BY` statement than `DISTINCT`. In your example you should add a group by at least on one col (some unique for example id). When you're using aggregates in query it is better to use group by, when using only joins - distinct is enough.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, sir. I'm sure it's correct. And I'm sorry to have wasted your time, but Strawberry was right. I'm not getting duplicate values. I had double entries in my database. It was just returning the data correctly.